# Tyepscript Error 2322 - Cannot init constant of generic type union of 2 optional index signatures

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

**TypeScript Version:**  4.1.3

**Search Terms:**
Error 2322
Type is not assignable to type

**Issue**
Type `ElementShape` has 2 index signature and both of them can be undefined - they have "?" before the ":"

Why I cannot initialize a constant of generic type `ElementShape` with only the common keys?
Also `Partial<ElementShape<A>>` gave the same error.

**Code**

```typescript
const element_def = {
    element1: {
        title: {}
    },
    element2: {
        price: {}
    }
} as const;

export type ElementName = 'element1' | 'element2';

export type CommonKeys = 'id' | 'active';

export type ElementShape<A extends ElementName> = 
   { [k in CommonKeys]?: string } &
   { [k in keyof typeof element_def[A]]?: number }


export function myFunc<A extends ElementName>(){

    let myconst:ElementShape<A> = {id: '', active: ''};
            // ~~~ Type '{ id: string; active: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ElementShape<A>'. Type '{ id: string; active: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [k in keyof { readonly element1: { readonly title: {}; }; readonly element2: { readonly price: {}; }; }[A]]?: number | undefined; }'.

    let mypartial:Partial<ElementShape<A>> = {id: '', active: ''};
             // ~~~  Type '{ id: string; active: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<ElementShape<A>>'.

    console.log(myconst, mypartial);

}
```

**Compiler Options**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "moduleResolution": 2,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "jsx": "React",
    "module": "ESNext"
  }
}
```

**[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgGzgWzmKB9AJnAZjAXhgG8AoASERTSgEYAuEi8qASyiUeIF8LuAaClVToATF2YAHAE6tgcLr3K9uMAIYQYoSFADcpUnAAekkNNhQAnpLgwAokhFQAcmtSEYAcmE1anmAA+Xj5invqGJmYW1rYAwiDIyOAA0nCWmkSerFj+QZ5qwGwAbnBhBsam5jBWNvaONADKABZqNgA8AILwRlBoWJoO1OiuqAB8HqQwU8QwANoA1jCsYDDxiSlpEAC6APyM0LJgAOYwqgBkk9Nzi8sw82kg+DVwj-D16Nh4sx1bu4xgAFdkAAjODSU4GCKVWC4AFgQqscAwZCWABicOAnW6vTA-TqQxcbjgowAFABKMgUJCwFHaaD0QZOZqtOCdcZEYjZRieTz8dQIkrczzcfRTMXisUAeklMAAfvKYAAVGJeGZcmAHZZHXT84oKDVQQ7a07+ViaMAgWAaCCsI5gNTApDVEDVFWeRmNFrtDqjTwAOiVbrVWH2hq1OoKetDRp13FN5st6ggNrtDqdUBdz1V1yWK3ulleM2kcDUWHACEsbwJDBIMGLpfLlbYHH1PFjOvrZbAFarTnEtc7jZgMjkrZFp1j31+exggJBYMCMDhOFwyzgWFj-oM5GpyOsanMrDUCHoAAUD2xj20Pehmd7RuySOqeXzI6xBV5haKJT+YNK5Qqga1J4wbRuGurvvqmrHJuSwJlaya2vajq2BmrrAeeh5XjeUB3qyPq+n6250iASB+ggIBHCStLgNAfIopIF5HggZLhNwQA)**